I can load GLTF files from a URL asynchronously. I want to do the same with drag/drop GLTF files
The code I am working on supports loading GLTF models from remote URLs.  I made a small async function that also adds some meta data to the GLTF object which is used later.
It works great.
Now, I want to support the ability to drag GLTF files onto the page and use the result in my existing code - transparently (code shouldn't care if it was downloaded from a URL or from the local machine via a drag/drop).
I have working code to drag/drop a GLTF onto my page and use GLTFLoader.parse() on the file object you get from the drop event.
However, I would like to move that to an async function so when I build my loader promises array, I can either pass in a 'load from URL' function or a 'load and parse this file object' one and once they return a GLTF object, I can use them in the same way.
Here is some pseudo(ish) code for what I mean:
// This works perfectly
async function loadGLTFUrl(data) {
    let result = await GLTFLoader.loadAsync(data.url);
    result.scene.userData = data;
    return result;
}

// This is what I am having trouble with
async function loadGLTFFileObject(data) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(data.fileobject);

    let result = await fr.onload = () => {
        getGLTFLoader().parse(fr.result, '', function (gltf) {
            result.scene.userData = data;
            return result
        });
    };
}


// Elsewhere in the code
let promises = []
promises.push(loadGLTFUrl(data1));
promises.push(loadGLTFFileObject(data2));

Promise.all(promises).then((loaded_gltfs) => {
    loaded_gltfs.forEach(function (gltf) {
        // do stuff with the loaded gltf and gltf.scene
        // and not care if it was loaded via a URL or 
        // if it was dropped onto the page
    });
});

Can someone point me in the right direction for code in loadGLTFFileObject() that does what I want?
EDIT:
Maybe it's as simple as:
function loadGLTFFromFileObject(fo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            gltfLoader.parse(reader.result, '', function (gltf) {
                resolve(gltf, null, reject);
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fo);
    });
}

Certainly seems to work - just not sure if it's correct.
